# how can i generate different output files for their respective input files in hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have used standard wordcount example from net which gives output of several input files into a single output files but i just want output of different input files into their respective different output files.So is there any way to do this in java. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the question? You want only the output of the mappers?

Comment: I want separate wordcount for each input file. The standard wordcount program gives combined output for all the input files.

Answer (score 0):

You can approach the requirement in the following way:
- Getting file name in Mapper is not easy but can be achieved. by below code in mapper:

```
        Path inputPath = null;
    InputSplit inputSplit = reporter.getInputSplit();
    String name = inputSplit.getClass().getName();
    if ("org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileSplit".compareTo(name) == 0) {
        FileSplit fs = (FileSplit) inputSplit;
        inputPath = fs.getPath();
    }
    if ("org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.TaggedInputSplit".compareTo(name) == 0) {
        TaggedInputSplit tis = (TaggedInputSplit) inputSplit;
        InputSplit iis = tis.getInputSplit();
        String iname = iis.getClass().getName();
        if ("org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileSplit".compareTo(iname) == 0) {
            FileSplit fs = (FileSplit) iis;
            inputPath = fs.getPath();
        }
    }
```

- Now add the file name to your Map output key. So your map output key can be one of the following:
           - Complex Writable with 2 fields - the file name & word from mapper
           or Just a Text with concatenated key of 2 components - the file name & word from mapper
- Now you need a custom partitioned & Comparator to divide this into diff reducers so each file name goes to diff reducer and same word from same file go to same reducer. You can find several examples online for this.

This should get you going.